# JavaScript - Fix image no matter the size of the window

Tags: javascript, html, css

The image is moving depending on the size of the screen, I would like to fix it on the top middle. How do I do it? Here is 2 screenshots explaining:

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

HTML:

```
<div class="logo"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.logo {
  background:url(../img/logo.png) no-repeat;
  position:absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  left:50%;
  top:30%;
  height:120px;  
  width:175px;
  margin:-115px 0px 0px -112px;
}
```

Comment: CSS:.logo {
    background:url(../img/logo.png) no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
 display: inline-block;
    left:50%;
    top:30%;
    height:120px;                  
    width:175px;     

    margin:-115px 0px 0px -112px;  
}

Comment: At first glance, it looks like the images are both too far left -- and your left margin (-112px) looks suited to a wider image than the one you have.  I'd try changing to a left margin of -88px and see if it looks better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use translate:

```
.logo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    height:120px;                  
    width:175px;     
    background:url(../img/logo.png) no-repeat;
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/78ead5u0/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `calc` function in CSS.

Resize your window to see it's effect (in fullscreen).

```css
.logo{
  position: absolute;
  width: 175px;
  height: 120px;
  top: 30%;
  left: calc(50% - (175px / 2)); /* 50% parent width - half_of_image_width */
  
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.container{
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo"></div>
</div>
```